# Package operation failed Errors were encountered while processing: xserver-common-lts-raring

Tags: package-management, dpkg, xserver

Before starting with my problem description, I would like to say that this is my very first time using Ubuntu or anything related to Linux!

Now my question!

I have installed the very last distribution of Ubuntu in my laptop (MSI FX620DX).

After a few updates I tried to install new applications such like **Gparted** or **Synaptic**... but it has been impossible to even get the package installed.

The same happens with any other application that I would like to install.

After launching the installation I get each time the same message:

```
*Package operation failed
The installation or removal of a software package failed.
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 158448 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing xserver-common-lts-raring ...
Removing 'diversion of /usr/lib/xorg/protocol.txt to /usr/lib/xorg/protocol-precise.txt by xserver-common-lts-raring'
dpkg-divert: error: rename involves overwriting `/usr/lib/xorg/protocol.txt' with
  different file `/usr/lib/xorg/protocol-precise.txt', not allowed
dpkg: error processing xserver-common-lts-raring (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 xserver-common-lts-raring*
```

I have tried several things that I found in different forums, but I could not find a solution for this.

Any idea or suggestion please?

Update:
When I run the software updater,it says that only a partial upgrade is possible.

Then I get the following msg:

```
    Could not install 'xserver-common-lts-raring'
    subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 2

    Could not install the upgrades

    The upgrade has aborted. Your system could be in an unusable state. A recovery will run now (dpkg --configure -a).
```

Any clue??

Update:

```
    rs@rs-GE620-GE620DX-FX620DX-FX623:~$ sudo uname -a
    [sudo] password for rs: 
    Linux rs-GE620-GE620DX-FX620DX-FX623 3.8.0-32-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 1         22:35:23 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
    rs@rs-GE620-GE620DX-FX620DX-FX623:~$ sudo lsb_release -a
    No LSB modules are available.
    Distributor ID: Ubuntu
    Description:    Ubuntu 13.04
    Release:    13.04
    Codename:   raring

    rs@rs-GE620-GE620DX-FX620DX-FX623:~$ sudo dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-video-intel
    ii  xserver-xorg-video-intel                  2:2.21.6-0ubuntu4.3                      amd64        X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx    display driver
    rc  xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-raring        2:2.21.6-0ubuntu4.1~precise1            amd64        X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx display driver
```

Comment: Edit your question and paste the output of these commands: `sudo uname -a`, `sudo lsb_release -a` and `sudo dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-video-intel`

Answer (score 1):

This solved it for me-
Go to /var/lib/dpkg/info
Edit xserver-common-lts-raring.postrm
Remove the if-else condition completely. Also, had removed -e from the first line (read somewhere).
Would suggest keeping a backup of the file in case an issue happens later on.

Answer (score 0):

After [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/343401/157741) solution to a somehow similar problem, maybe you should run `apt-get install -f` and if that fails too, perhaps try `apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-raring`, or with a `-f`, as the update in the link suggests. And if it was me, I would also try purging and reinstalling `xserver-xorg-video-intel`, probably to no avail but who knows, though, Of course many here know.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you put grub on your `/dev/sda` ( your HDD ) and not on the ext3 partition. 
In other words when installing Ubuntu set your  **Device for boot loader installation** to `/dev/sda` or `sdb` or `sdc`...
At least that's what turned out to be the problem in my case...

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:

```
cd /usr/lib/xorg/
sudo mv protocol.txt protocol.txt.backup
apt-get -f install
```

So you `cd` into the directory where the problem file lives, change the problem file's name so it is not referenced by the shell script that runs during update (which is where the problem appears to be), and then run the fix broken install command.

However, I'm not sure this is the best way to fix this problem.